# Passing parameters to classic ASP include files

Tags: asp-classic, include

I have to use classic ASP to build a website.
I want to be able to use include files for the header and footer.

How do I pass variables to the include files so that I can affect such things as titles etc.
Here is some examples of what I want to do:

index.asp

```
<%
dim title
title="TITLE"

'Server.Execute("header.inc") <--- Note I tried this but it didnt work also
%>
<!--#include file="header.inc" -->
```

header.inc

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><% Response.write title %></title>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.write` is client-side JavaScript. What you want in header.inc is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><%=title%></title>
```

Or more verbosely:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><% Response.Write title %></title>
```

Other than that, what you have should work (without the `Server.Execute`, just do the include as you show further down).

Comment: Cheers I spotted that mistake but it still doesn't work, I think I have to use Session

Comment: @Chris: This works just fine, you don't need to use Session for it. I just tested it to be sure.

Comment: @Chris, What T.J. Crowder has posted is working 100%. You will only find obstacles, with this method, if you want to dynamically include files..

Answer (score 1):

An include file is rendered/interpreted in-line... I would just set some values in the main file, and check for them in the include file.  No?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell using sessions is the only way

```
<%
Session("title") = "mytitle"

Server.Execute("header.inc")
%>

<title><% response.write(Session("title")) %></title>
```

This [article](http://www.devingdc.com/?p=29) also shows the same results

Comment: No, you don't need to use sessions. I just tested my answer and it works just fine.

Comment: Use <!--#include file="header.inc" --> (as in your original example) to include the header file and then you can simply reference the title variable as @TJCrowder shows. When you include a file, ASP imports the contents of the included file before processing any of the code on the page. Any page-scope variables defined in the ASP page will also be available in the include file (and vice versa).

Comment: Also, mis-using sessions like this is a categorically terrible idea.